manifest.json issue - chrome extension
I'm having trouble with following one of the first examples in the developer documentation for making chrome extentions. But this json in the manifest file is returning an error and I have absolutely no idea why.
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Reading time",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Add the reading time to Chrome Extension documentation articles",
  "icons": { 
    "16": "images/icon-16.png",
    "32": "images/icon-32.png",
    "48": "images/icon-48.png",
    "128": "images/icon-128.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["scripts/content.js"],
      "matches": [
        "https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/*",
        "https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

I tried switching the syntax. I tried looking everywhere I could on stack overflow and I didn't find my issue.


The code is correct. 2) What is the exact error message?


@wOxxOm it doesn't like the icons for some reason: Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 6, column: 5, Syntax error.


Since this code is correct, apparently your actual file is somehow different, a popular problem is using a fancy quote instead of the standard ASCII ". 2) Try re-saving the file in a different editor. 3) Make sure these icons exist in the subfolder images.

